# Calendar.YEAR showing wrong year

Tags: android, date

I am using the calendar functionality in one of my methods. The Calendar.Year doesn seem to be working , it shows the wrong date .

`MyCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`  --> Shows 5 (which is correct today . i.e, thursday)
`MyCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` --> Shows 1 (which is wrong today is 18)
`MyCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)`        --> Shows 0 (which is wrong it should be 8 for September)
`MyCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)`         --> Shows 1970 (which is wrong , it should be 2014))

My code :

```
import java.util.Calendar;
public static String getDate(Calendar MyCal){

return  MyCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"/"+MyCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))+"/"+ MyCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

}
```

Not sure why I am getting the wrong dats. My Android tab shows the correct date in system settings.

Can you please advise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt very much that the Calendar is wrong, you're probably using it wrong. Put all the relevant code (initialization, population) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: have added the code in

Comment: what is `MyCal`. The proper way to access a current calendar is `Calendar.getInstance()`

Comment: You can find some examples here: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/DateTimeCalendar.html. I suppose your MyCal is extending Calendar, but you're not initializing it right.

Comment: Initialization was the issue , put it in as an answer i'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some examples here: [ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/DateTimeCalendar.html](http://ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/DateTimeCalendar.html). I suppose your MyCal is extending Calendar, but you're not initializing it right.